# How to consume Web Service class library in WCF operation contract method

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have a Web Service class library contains a resuable method:

```
NameSpace RestfulService
{
   [ServiceContract]
   [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode =   AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
   [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
   public class commonService
   {
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "call/{conn}/{sp}/{args=null}")]
        public Stream Call(string conn, string sp, string args)
        {
          // code for take care of access database and serialize object SqlDataReader 
          // return new MemoryStream(asBytes); 
        }
   }
}
```

The question is how should I use this service and the "Call" method in other WCF web services in the same namespace. Do I have to create a instance of ServiceHost for it or I should just create a instance of commonService class? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

On Server side, you do not need to create Service reference. You simply need to create object of "commonservice" class and call its method over the created object.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. I just wanted to make sure if I understood correctly. The UriTemplate for the method is "call/{conn}/{sp}/{args=null}", I can just ignore it? Instead, I do this: CommonService service = new CommonService; service.Call(conn, sp, args)?

Comment: Yes, you are right. There is no importance of attribute when class instances are created in classes across WCF Implementation layer.